# C# Adding a List<int> to a class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    private string sFirst_name1;
    public string sParent1FirstName
    {
        get { return sFirst_name1; }
        set { sFirst_name1 = value; }
    }

    private string sLast_name1;
    public string sParent1LastName
    {
        get { return sLast_name1; }
        set { sLast_name1 = value; }
    }

    private List<int> lChild_ID;
    public List<int> lChildID
    {
        get { return lChild_ID; }
        set { lChild_ID = value; }
    }
public Parent(string sP1FN, string sP1LN, List<int> lCID)
    {
        lChild_ID= new List<int>();
        sFirst_name1 = sP1FN;
        sLast_name1 = sP1LN;
        lChild_ID = lCID;

    }
```

I create an instance of the class and add it to a List of type Parent with the line:

```
lParents.Add(new Parent(sParent1FNTemp, sParent1LNTemp,lParentChildIDTemp));
```

Where lParentChildIDTemp is just a null integer List.

Later on, I am trying to update the int list of the object at a specified index by saying:

```
lParents[iIndex].lChildID.Add(++iIDCounters);
```

And I get a null reference exception. I'm not too sure why, but I think it has something to do with my constructor for my class. The weird thing is, I have another class that does pretty much the same thing but it doesn't throw the exception. If anyone has any clues, I would be greatful.

Comment: `Where lParentChildIDTemp is just a null integer List.` ...... `And I get a null reference exception`.  I think you answered your own question.

Comment: You are assigning `lChild_ID` twice in the constructor.

Comment: it would be helpful if you noted where the exception is being thrown from - there are a few places it looks like you could have a null exception under normal execution...it seems likely that it is a null being passed into your constructor

Comment: See marked duplicate for general advice debugging and fixing `NullReferenceException`. If that is insufficient, post a new question in which you include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the List of int argument in the ctor and why not use auto props:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(string sP1FN, string sP1LN)
    {
        LChildID = new List<int>();
        sFirst_name1 = sP1FN;
        sLast_name1 = sP1LN;
    }

    public List<int> LChildID { get; set; }
```

If you're not familiar with auto-implemented properties, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Plus, you could also overload the ctor:

```
    public Parent(string sP1FN, string sP1LN, List<int> lCID)
    {
        LChildID = lCID;
        sFirst_name1 = sP1FN;
        sLast_name1 = sP1LN;
    }
```

Comment: there are so many things about his code style that are very unusual for C# - but I'm assuming he is not using auto props because this is pseudocode for this question

Comment: also - this is not an answer to his question and is quite unrelated to the question at hand...in the future, use comments for this stuff

Comment: @RobertPetz I see what you mean, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Give your property is null, you should make sure you are not access null values to call methods or properties. If you do that, you will get an `NullReferenceException`. Try this:

```
var childIds = lParents[iIndex].lChildID;
if (childIds != null)
{
    childIds.Add(++iIDCounters);
}
```

In your constructor, you could check the if the argument is null and define a default list int. If you for to set the argument, even if it is null, you will get null.

```
public Parent(string sP1FN, string sP1LN, List<int> lCID)
{
    sFirst_name1 = sP1FN;
    sLast_name1 = sP1LN;
    if (lCID == null)       
    {
       lChild_ID = new List<int>();
    }
    else
    {
       lChild_ID = lCID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently you want to be able to pass in the `lChildID` during construction, change the constructor as so:

```
public Parent(string sP1FN, string sP1LN, List<int> lCID) {
    sFirst_name1 = sP1FN;
    sLast_name1 = sP1LN;
    lChild_ID = lCID ?? new List<int>();
}
```